# Functions using tuple in Swift 3.1

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have a sample code(following). 
It works very well in Swift 3.0.2 but Swift 3.1 does not.
What kind of problems?
How to resolve this problem?

```
typealias abcTuple = (a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, c: CGFloat)
class SomeClass: NSObject {

    var a: CGFloat = 0.0
    var b: CGFloat = 0.0
    var c: CGFloat = 0.0

    func setValues(a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, c: CGFloat) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }

    func setValues(_ values: abcTuple) {
        self.a = values.a
        self.b = values.b
        self.c = values.c
    }

    func showValues() {
        print("a: \(self.a) b: \(self.b) c: \(self.c)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of the second `setValues` method to something different like `setTuple`, the code will compile fine. For example, I defined the second method as:

```
func setTuple(_ values: abcTuple) {
    self.a = values.a
    self.b = values.b
    self.c = values.c
}
```

And everything compiles fine.